# In an SPA, how to keep server-side data stored in localStorage or sessionStorage from getting too stale?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, vue.js, single-page-application

It makes a lot of sense to store UI-only data in localStorage (browser/machine) or sessionStorage (browser tab) to reduce the complexity of communication across components. The flux/redux patterns on top of these storage forms make it even better. But this data doesn't need to be in sync with a server, it's only for complicated UI purposes.

Now I'm a little confused when it comes to the data that does need to stay in sync with the server. Navbars, notifications, and footers are examples of components that may hold server-side data which do not get removed from the view in an SPA application. Currently what I do is keep the server-side data for these components in localStorage so that I can run a single function on a timer that refreshes all the data at once at certain intervals. Other components get regularly created/updated/destroyed as the user moves around in the app, so they don't pull anything from localStorage (they pull their own data from the server when they need it).

**Is the approach I'm using the commonly accepted approach? Or is there a better and more standard way in the long term to keep this data from going stale? Something that the veterans of SPAs are using.**

The only alternative I can think is using long-polling ajax calls in each component or web-sockets. I'm not even sure what the general reasons are that anyone stores server-side data in localStorage any way, as I'm writing an SPA app for the very first time. Any extra insight would be helpful.

Comment: Your approach will work fine but you are doing to many requests just to check for updates. A better way to go is to use sockets (a service like [pusher.js](https://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start) could work  ) than your front end will be notified on any change that  happens in the server side. the message coming from the back end can contain all the data you need to update and you can even send a complete object to replace the existing one on your browser storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no generally 'accepted approach' I believe. The golden rule is to **not** over engineer your code. Instead, start simple and refactor when whatever you have doesn't work anymore (you decide when: becomes hard to maintain / hard to add features, etc). That being said, it seems like your solution is a good start and you shouldn't think about it too much. 
Of course, it all depends on the amount & type of data you wish to store on localStorage. Here's what you can consider doing:

#### 1. Sockets

Sockets are an alternative to your approach. You can either host a socket server yourself (most languages have their own implementation, but [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for Node is a very popular choice) or go for a service that provides a client socket API. Popular options are:
- [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
- [pusher](https://pusher.com/)

Mind you, going with a 3rd party service might lock you in, which is not necessarily a good idea.

If you go with sockets, you can also implement them in the components that get regularly created/updated/destroyed. Sockets will come in handy for lists, but generally your users will appreciate having the latest data everywhere in the app.

#### 2. Service worker w/ indexedDB

An improvement on your approach could be to use a service worker in order to do periodical updates. Mind you, you won't be able to use localStorage from a service worker. In that case, you need to switch to indexedDB for storage ([support is generally OK](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)).

You might consider this alternative if you want to do more frequent updates (for a performance boost), need offline support or want to keep the storage logic completely separated. On top of that, you'll get a ton of features with indexedDB. If the data you want to store locally is complex, you might want to take advantage of it.

However, this could be a great example of over engineering your code, so avoid it unless there's no other way.

Take a look at [this react boilerplate](https://github.com/localnerve/react-pwa-reference) or [this vue boilerplate](https://github.com/BosNaufal/vue-simple-pwa) for some service worker examples. Don't think they focus on the storage bit though :)

Comment: Great answer. And that vue PWA boilerplate was very helpful.

Comment: IndexedDB does not work in Safari Private Mode if this is important.